# django and sqlite on production! my db file has nothing, why?

Tags: django, sqlite

i am stuck again in one problem. i have been delevoping my project locally in django. everything works fine, and now i uploaded all project to server(virtual). now my db is not working, i mean, once i click the button which should bring data from db, it doesnot bring anything from db. can it be that i configured my sqlite on server in a wrong way?

basically i did nothing on server, so i think i should first configure my sqlite on server then it will work right? can you please help me how to do this. OS is linux. i hope, the configuration doesnot differ that much between OS versions of linux..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed your project's dependencies?

Are you running a virtualenv or system environment?

What do you mean with 'click a button', post the script behind it

Does your production environment runserver without errors?

Try the command line and check for errors:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

errors ?

```
./manage.py runserver
```

errors ?

```
./manage.py shell

>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>> print User.objects.all()
```

errors ?

```
>> import sqlite3
```

errors ?

Comment: yeah, i did this. i saw in the console of FF, it says: DatabaseError at /ajax/
attempt to write a readonly database

it means that the right to write to db file ist not there, how do i do it? with chown username folder/file.db  right?

Comment: chmod/chown your database file so django can write to it.. It's probably created by the root user, which isn't the same as apache, thus causing this problem

Comment: now, it is saying: unable to open database file. i did chown username folder, then chown username folder/file.db. Then chmod 777 folder, and chmod 777 folder/file.db

Comment: by the way, the path to db file is this in my settings.py: 
'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'stahlbank.db'), is that okay?

Comment: I don't know what project_path holds, but I suppose that looks just fine. There's no reason to chmod to 777, besides the fact it's insecure, 755 should be fine. I think your user is the problem. What user is running the apache(?) process? Use 'top' to find out.

Comment: i did top, but in 'USER' column i see only 'root'. how do i see exactly who is running the apache?

Comment: "ps aux | grep apache" while it is running

Comment: oh okay, so the root is running the apache. now i need enable apache to be able to write/read the django's db file, right? how do i do this with chown/chmod?

Comment: please help, i cannot get rid of the problem. i found that the root is running apache, so i chowned root to all the dirs path till database file, but still not working..

Comment: what happends when you delete or backup the db file (mv stahlbank.db stahlbank.backup) and you run syncdb, does the system create the file? It probably does and you're likely looking at a basic permissions error

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file

Comment: yeah, it is creating again. where are the basic permissions error to see?

Comment: ls -ahl, I would read the serverfault thread there's probably something you are overlooking

Comment: now it is saying: IOError sys.stdout access restricted by mod_wsgi

Comment: That's caused by a 'print' statement in your python code somewhere. In production there is no command line to write to and you should use logging for that purpose

Comment: oh okay, i think, i am using command 'print' in my code, thats why. but now it should work..

Comment: hey ArgsKwargs, problem solved. many many thanks for help! i LOVE Stackoverflow! Great people here!